# passing different id automatically in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table like this:

```
Locid       Paydate                 DelDate                 vtid

5           2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000   7
5           2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000   8
6           2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000   7
6         2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000     8
7           2013-05-07 18:36:50.000 2013-05-07 18:58:32.000   7
```

I have one stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[performance] @locid INTEGER=NULL
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT l.LocName,
             v.Vtype,
             SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))                                                   AS TotalDiff,
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)))) AS Average
      FROM   Transaction_tbl t
             LEFT JOIN VType_tbl v
               ON t.vtid = v.vtid
             LEFT JOIN Location_tbl l
               ON t.Locid = l.Locid
      WHERE  t.Locid = @locid
      GROUP  BY v.Vtype,
                l.LocName
  END
```

,in this at a time i can able to pass only one locid,some time i need to get out put 2 locid in one data set. so how i can pass two locid automatically.

Comment: What version of SQL Server and what do you mean "pass two locid automatically?" How can it be automatic?

Comment: sql server 2008,pass two locid means some time i want to pass locid 5, and 6 .

Comment: It was the "automatic" bit that I was unclear about. Your call to the procedure will need to supply these parameter values somehow.

Comment: not able pass both locid together right? i mean while executing this stored procedure first it should take the value of locid =5,then locid=6,like that.so that i have to use any for loop in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change the stored procedure to accept a table valued parameter (which can then accept an arbitrary number of `locid`s)

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[LocationIds] AS TABLE(
    locid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
```

Then

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[performance] 
@LocationIds [dbo].[LocationIds] READONLY
AS
```

And change the `WHERE` to

```
 WHERE  t.Locid in (SELECT locid FROM  @LocationIds  )
```

Also add `l.Locid` to the `GROUP BY` list unless the name is guaranteed unique.

Comment: actullay this locid is dynamic value.some time locid will come upto 10,so i have declare 10 locid ??

Comment: @user2603688 - No. In that case use the table valued parameter.

Comment: can you able to re-write this stored procedure with proper code

Comment: how to use table valued parameter

Comment: +1 I didn't know about table valued parameters, reading up on it now ty.

Comment: @user2603688 - Regarding your question about how to use table valued parameter are you calling this stored procedure from TSQL or ADO.NET or some other way?

Comment: sir,i re-writed my stored proceure,getting out put un-orderd,how i can make that in orderd

Comment: @user2603688 - Add an `ORDER BY` after the `GROUP BY`. Please don't edit your questions to ask something entirely different though. It will just be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

To handle an indertiminate number of id's then you could have them passed as a comma separated string (varchar), split it into a table and then join to it.

Something like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[performance]
    (@ids VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @xml xml = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@ids,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

    SELECT 
        l.LocName,
        v.Vtype,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)) AS TotalDiff,
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1), 
            AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), 
            DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)))) AS Average
    FROM Transaction_tbl t
    JOIN (
        SELECT t.value('.','INT') id
        FROM @xml.nodes('//root/r') a(t)
    ) x ON x.id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN VType_tbl v
           ON t.vtid = v.vtid
    LEFT JOIN Location_tbl l
           ON t.Locid = l.Locid
    GROUP BY v.Vtype, l.LocName
END
GO
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ae5a/2)